# How can I run difftool with only my work ignoring merges

Tags: git

Let's say I have two remotes.  `origin` (source of truth) and `fork` (my fork).  I start a new branch based off of origin, and make some commits and push them to my fork

```
git checkout -b test origin/master
# Make commit A
# Make commit B
git push -u fork test  # Now I'm tracking fork/test rather than origin/master
```

A couple of days go by, and I fetch origin and merge those changes in and keep working:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin   # Head is now at C (the merge commit)
# Make commit D
# Make commit E
```

At this point I'd like a diff which collects together A, B, D, and E (ignoring the merge commit C as well as any other new changes that got merged in from origin) in a unified diff.

Also, I'd like it in my difftool (ideally with -d).

```
    origin/master
0------1------2------3
 \                    \
  A----------B---------C----D----E
```

So I basically want 0-A, A-B, B-C, and D-E.

Comment: `git diff` can compare any revision to any other revision. Find a name that identifies revision `0`, one that identifies revision `A`, and run `git diff <name1> <name2>` and you get the difference from 0 to A. All `git difftool` does is extract the files from the commits and run some other diff tool on them: a less efficient, but more flexible, version of `git diff` (`git diff` only "virtually" extracts the files from each commit rather than having to put them into real but temporary files).

Comment: Remember that every commit is a full snapshot of all of its files. So `git diff <name-of-0> <name-of-E>` gets you a recipe that would change all of the files that are in snapshot 0 into all of the files that are in snapshot E. Any time you want a diff that omits some particular commit, you can't get it until you make a new series of commits that omits that particular commit, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use three dot syntax.

`git difftool -d origin/master...HEAD`

Some people suggested to just find the commit naming 0, but the whole point is that that isn’t easy. origin/master has diverged since i branched so no longer refers to the original commit from which i branched.